# What is the difference between this two code blocks.? React JS Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

This is my useState hook .

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: ""
  });
```

This is my first code block.

```
1. function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    if(name === "fName"){
      setFullName({
        fName:value,
        lName:fullName.lName
      });
    }else if(name === "lName"){
      setFullName({
        fName : fullName.fName,
        lName : value
      });
    }
  }
```

This is my second code block.

```
2.function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    setFullName(prevValue => {
      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
          fName: value,
          lName: prevValue.lName
        };
      } else if (name === "lName") {
        return {
          fName: prevValue.fName,
          lname: value
        };
      }
    });
  }
```

Both things working same but I can't see the difference between them behind the seen.

Comment: If you know about closure in javascript, you will understand like when to do this.
Lets say we have multiple names to update in a loop with other stuffs. and we are doing setName(name) for each item. by  the time it sets state for one, chances are 'name' might have changed. In that case we use callback to see what was prev Value. This is useful when we are doing computation based on last value, so that we get correct value

Answer (score 3):

In the first code block a condition check is performed *before* the function call. If either condition passes, the function will be executed.

In the second block the function is **always** executed. In the case where neither condition is true, you just wasted valuable processor time calling a function that didn’t need to be.

Answer (score 1):

if you use if statement without a 'return' statement, the program will continue executing the code after checking if block.

```
1. function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    if(name === "fName"){
      setFullName({
        fName:value,
        lName:fullName.lName
      });
    }else if(name === "lName"){
      setFullName({
        fName : fullName.fName,
        lName : value
      });
    }
```

//the code here will be executed
}

on the other hand, if you use 'return' inside 'if' and if condition is met then the code after if statement will not be executed.

```
2.function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    setFullName(prevValue => {
      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
          fName: value,
          lName: prevValue.lName
        };
      } else if (name === "lName") {
        return {
          fName: prevValue.fName,
          lname: value
        };
      }
    });
```

//the code here will not be executed if condition is true
}

Answer (score 1):

Well, here both code blocks are essentially doing the same thing. Using the `prevValue` the way you have done in the second code block can be useful when it is imperative that you keep track of the previous state value.

For example, let's say a state value for a variable called number and a function called increment:

```
const [number, setNumer] = useState(0);
const increment = () => {
  setNumber(number + 1)
  setNumber(number + 1)
  setNumber(number + 1)
}
```

Here, it is tempting to think that the answer would be 3. But instead, each time this function is simply adding 0 (i.e. the value of number) plus 1. In order words, it is just setting the value of number to 1 three times.

We could grab the previous value of state to make this function behave as expected.

```
const increment = () => {
  setNumber(prevValue => prevValue + 1)
  setNumber(prevValue => prevValue + 1)
  setNumber(prevValue => prevValue + 1)
}
```